# Using c++ complex functions in Cython

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython

I am trying to do a complex exponential in Cython.

I have been able to cobble together the following code for my `pyx`:

```
from libc.math cimport sin, cos, acos, exp, sqrt, fabs, M_PI, floor, ceil

cdef extern from "complex.h":
    double complex cexp(double complex z)

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange, parallel

def try_cexp():
    cdef:
        double complex rr1
        double complex rr2
    rr1 = 1j
    rr2 = 2j

    print(rr1*rr2)

    #print(cexp(rr1))
```

Note that the `print(cexp(rr1))` is commented. When the line is active, I get the following error when running `setup.py`:

```
error: command 'C:\\WinPYthon\\Winpython-64bit-3.4.3.6\\python-3.4.3.amd64\\scripts\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Note that when `cexp` is commented out, everything runs expected... I can run `setup.py`, and when I test the function it prints out the product of the two complex numbers.

Here is my `setup.py` file. Note that it includes code to run `openmp` in Cython using g++:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["CC"] = "g++-4.7"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++-4.7"

# These were added based on some examples I had seen of cexp in Cython. No effect.
#import pyximport
#pyximport.install(reload_support=True)

ext_modules = [
    Extension('complex_test',
              ['complex_test.pyx'],
              language="c++",
              extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
              extra_link_args=['-fopenmp', '-lm'])  # Note that '-lm' was
              # added due to an example where someone mentioned g++ required
              # this. Same results with and without it.
    ]

setup(
    name='complex_test',
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
    )
```

Ultimately my goal is to speed up a calcualtion that looks like `k*exp(z)`, where `k` and `z` are complex. Currently I am using Numerical expressions, however that has a large memory overhead, and I believe that it's possible to optimize further than it can.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you found them to be faster than `cmath`?

Comment: Well I originally tried doing my complex exponential using Euler's law with Sines and cosines comma but that was not as efficient as I hoped

Comment: Well okay, but have you tried `cmath` yet?

Comment: From what I understand the complex functions are in complex.h not in math.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [**`cexp`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/cexp) instead of [**`exp`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/exp) as it is in `C++`. Change your `cdef extern` to:

```
cdef extern from "<complex.h>" namespace "std":
    double complex exp(double complex z)
    float complex exp(float complex z)  # overload
```

and your print call to:

```
print(exp(rr1))
```

and it should work as a charm.

---

I know the compilation messages are lengthy, but in there you can find the error that points to the culprit:

```
complex_test.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_12complex_test_try_cexp(PyObject*)’:
complex_test.cpp:1270:31: error: cannot convert ‘__pyx_t_double_complex {aka std::complex<double>}’ to ‘__complex__ double’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__complex__ double cexp(__complex__ double)’
   __pyx_t_3 = cexp(__pyx_v_rr1);
```

It's messy, but you can see the cause. *You're supplying a `C++` defined type (`__pyx_t_double_complex` in Cython Jargon) to a `C` function which expects a different type (`__complex__ double`).

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't think I ever would have figured this out. There are no examples on the web I have seen with this answer... and I would never have thought to do that. I feel really dumb. Though in my defense, the Cython learning curve is steep. :D Question though @Jim... what if I want to define functions both for floats and doubles? Wouldn't there be a collision? Or will exp work on either? And oh my gosh... thanks again.

Comment: @KeithL I'm pretty sure you can overload the functions without issues, trying it yields expected results.

Comment: You are correct @Jim. And I was able to successfully build a Cython parallelized function, but unfortunately it still isn't as fast as the memory hogging Numexpr. :( Thanks again for your help! I think what I'm going to do is build this in Visual Studio as a dll and see if THAT is faster.